# Ubuntu 22.04 gnome remote desktop windows RDP username not set denying client

Tags: gnome, remote-desktop

I enabled the gnome-remote-desktop service and trying to connect from a windows machine. When I run the following command  `systemctl --user status gnome-remote-desktop.service` I can see that the service is active and running. However, every time I try to connect the service throws out this error: `Jun 04 11:20:04 <HOSTNAME> gnome-remote-de[13291]: [RDP] Username is not set, denying client`

I have, obviously, set the username on the windows RDP client in the following fashion:[image]

The hostname is clearly correct and firewall is not an issue as the gnome-remote-desktop service is seeing the connection requests everytime it hit connect and throwing up this username not set message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message `[RDP] Username is not set, denying client` does not refer to the credentials on the client side, but the ones stored in the keyring on the server side.

The remote desktop panel in gnome-control-center sets the credentials in the keyring. Upon receiving a new connection, gnome-remote-desktop (g-r-d) reads those credentials and creates a SAM database, which is then provided to FreeRDP, where the actual authentication happens.

g-r-d emits the message `[RDP] Username is not set, denying client` when it read the credentials, received `NULL` from its API call, while no error is set.

This happens in two scenarios:

1. The credentials are really not set (nothing could be found by the keyring daemon)
2. The keyring is not unlocked. The keyring is encrypted with the users password. It is automatically unlocked, when the user logs in locally on the server side itself with their password, because then the user password is just forwarded to the `login` keyring, which is usually the default keyring.
   If you e.g. use autologin, no user password is entered and therefore the keyring cannot be unlocked, because no password is entered.
   You can unlock the keyring on the server side manually after autologon by e.g. starting `searhorse` (GUI for managing keyrings) first and opening the default keyring.
   Seahorse will then ask for the users password, which then unlocks the keyring.

Comment: So, how do I RD to an Ubuntu 22.04 that's mounted up on a wall without mouse or keyboard (just an info screen) with autologin? I normally use SSH, but I need to get to the GUI.